# Download file from "protected" directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, download

how can I download a file from directory which is "protected" against direct access via .htaccess?

So the file is in `/var/www/web1/domain.com/protecteddirectory/file.png`

and I want to use a PHP-script which checks if user is allowed to download (already done) and initiates download after that.

This is my source so far:

```
public function downloadAttachment()
{       
    $id                             =   JRequest::getInt('id');

    $user                           =   JFactory::getUser();
    $model                          =   $this->getModel('Attachment');
    $item                           =   $model->getAttachment($id);
    if(!$user->guest)
    {
        echo "<p><strong>Check if you are allowed to download...</strong></p>";

        if($user->get('isRoot'))
        {
            echo "<p><strong>Preparing...</strong></p>";

            $filename = $item->filename; //Name to display
            $filepath = $item->filepath;      
            // start download now...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p><strong>You are not allowed to download this file...</strong></p>";
    }
}
```

How can I solve this? In best case the filetype is detected automatically because it's possible to download png, zip, txt, doc, pdf and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using this code:

```
$size       = filesize($file);
header ( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header ( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename ( $file ) );
header ( 'Expires: 0' );
header ( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
header ( 'Pragma: public' );
header ( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize ( $file ) );
ob_clean(); 
flush();
readfile ( $file );
exit();
```